# Using @Aspect with @Conditional

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, aspect

I want to conditionally create an `Aspect` depending on a value read from the properties file. (It is related to profiling, that's why the intended selective use).

I have tried to create a class that implements [Condition](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) and therefore the `matches()` method that would allow me to perform the validation necessary and set the output to the corresponding `Boolean`, enabling or disabling it.

```
@Aspect 
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public class MyAspect {
...
pointCuts, methods and etc...
...
}
```

Thing is: The `Aspect` is instantiated by Spring anyway apparently it does not respect the `@Conditional` annotation output.

Are there any caveats that I am missing here?

Versions:

```
Spring version: 4.1.4.RELEASE

AspectJ version: 1.7.3
```

(The project dependency tree is a bit 'complicated' so updating libs has to be taken with a grain of salt :) )

Comment: It is an `@Aspect` and not an `@Component`.. So it probably isn't scanned, and you might not even have annotation processing present.

Answer (score 2):

You could manage to achive a conditional `Aspect Behaviour` if you register your aspect as a component, as described in the [@EnableAspectJAutoProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) configuration.

From the docs:

> Enables support for handling components marked with AspectJ's @Aspect annotation, similar to functionality found in Spring's  XML element. To be used on @Configuration
>
> Note that **@Aspect beans may be component-scanned like any other**. Simply mark the aspect with both @Aspect and @Component:

So your problem should be solved by just adding @Component to your bean and setting up a proper component-scan if needed.

For example:

```
@Aspect
@Component 
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public class MyAspect {
...
pointCuts, methods and etc...
...
}
```